# AWS Glue Notebook: Failed to authenticate user due to missing information in request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm getting the following error on the Ohio server:
`Failed to authenticate user due to missing information in request.`

This suddenly started happening after using Glue for few months.

Error picture here

[image]

I've tried adding AWS onto my cookie allow list and still doesn't allow me. I've also tried restarting my machine and using another 2 browsers other than chrome yet still doesn't work. I'm the only one affected on the team it only happens on the Ohio server whilst NV etc work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. Check that your browser does not block third-party cookies. Any browser that blocks third-party cookies either by default or as a user-enabled setting will prevent notebooks from launching (the typical error message is `Failed to authenticate user due to missing information in the request.`)

Chrome: [Turn Off "Block Third-Party Cookies" in Chrome for Windows](https://support.alertlogic.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018127132-Turn-Off-Block-Third-Party-Cookies-in-Chrome-for-Windows)

Firefox: [Third-party cookies and Firefox tracking protection](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/third-party-cookies-firefox-tracking-protection)

Safari: [Clear cookies in Safari on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/safari/sfri11471/mac)

Comment: Yeah I had done all that and still didn't work. However, it works now and yesterday it was only Ohio that wasn't working so I believe it was a server problem on the AWS side.